# Kafka integration with RabbitMQ

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, confluent-platform

I want to integrate Kafka and RabbitMQ,

I am able to send the messages to RabbitMQ but the message are not being consumed. Channel number status shows - 0 in the RabbitMQ console.

Changed the user as Admin, but still the same issue.

Deployed Kafka through Confluent ( and not individual deployment of zookeeper Kafka etc) and also installed Rabbitmq connector through Confluent-hub as well.

Please help.

```
[2019-03-26 06:39:19,151] ERROR Consumer io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.ConnectConsumer@454774b5 (amq.ctag-Unaj3jmbQQctolAwNzU2SQ) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://guest@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5672/,1) threw an exception for channel AMQChannel(amqp://guest@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5672/,1) (com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler:124)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.MessageConverter.basicProperties(MessageConverter.java:127)
at io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.SourceRecordBuilder.sourceRecord(SourceRecordBuilder.java:40)
at io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.ConnectConsumer.handleDelivery(ConnectConsumer.java:69)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:100)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was evaluating the RabbitMQ Kafka Connector and came across this exact same error.

An AMQP message is made up of two parts. A header and the message content. I was only providing the message content and not the header.

You have to create a BasicProperties object with metadata. Java Docs can be viewed [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.5.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.5.4/com/rabbitmq/client/AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder.html#build()).

Then when you publish to RabbitMQ using the `basicPublish` method, use the BasicProperties object you created earlier as one of the arguments.

Java docs for basicPublish can be found [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.1.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.1.5/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#basicPublish(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties,%20byte[])).

Hope this helps